# how can I stop fizz from dancing around so much?

Tags: league-of-legends

Fizz drives me insane he jumps around the hits me then jumps around some more then siks his stupid shark on me and boom I'm dead.....Is there a way to avoid this champion, stop him from doing his lil dance or a sure way to counter him?

Answer (score 2):

Silence plays a key role in stopping fizz. or any hard cc. As long as you can stop him from trickster then you should be able to melt him as he is generally squishy. An item that can help with this if you are a caster is Zhonyas Hourglass. That way you can use it to avoid the shark damage and then turn on him. Other than that it is hard to counter the trickster from Fizz seeing as the point of it is to make him untargetable.

Answer (score 0):

Targeted stuns (Such as Taric's Dazzle) when his Playful/Trickster is on cd, but as an Assassin type character, his mobility is a strong aspect of him.

Comment: When the other team has a fizz I try and stay ver very far away because what Ive noticed is when he does that play/trick thing he does splash damage and he ends up getting 2 or 3 kills from just one team fight

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is if you are in ranked or draft mode and team captain, simply ban fizz or pick fizz yourself.  Otherwise, you can't stop fizz from using his untargetable skill, just like you can stop vlad from using his pool or a player from activating their zhonya's.  Simply try to force them to put it on cooldown through a gank, or simply outplay them.